# Pegando TimeInMillis e usando Timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

**Dúvida:**

Conheço duas formas e capturar um `TimeInMillis()` alguém sabe a diferença e qual é a mais eficiente? E se existe uma terceira forma de capturar esse valor?

---

**Opção 1:**

```
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

---

**Opção 2:**

```
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

---

**Problema:**

---

Percebi que existe uma classe chamada `TimeStamp` e não consigo passar os um `System.currentTimeMillis()` para ela.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(time);
```

Erro:

```
The constructor Timestamp(long) is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve estar importando o `Timestamp` incorreto, pois esse construtor sempre existiu. Verifique o `import`, o correto é [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp%28long%29).

Sobre obter o tempo em milissegundos, `System.currentTimeMillis()` é mais rápido porque é uma função nativa e não necessita da criação de objetos. Se criar um `new java.util.Date()` o construtor internamente chama o método `currentTimeMillis()`, assim como a instância de `Calendar` (verifiquei apenas o `GregorianCalendar`).

Comment: Problema é o `import java.security.Timestamp` que estava errado no meu código, troquei ele e consegui usar o `Timestamp`. A explicação do `TimeMillis`  com relação a objeto ajudou bastante.